# Get data between tags for tags that fit defined CSS selector with Python's HTMLParser

Tags: python, html, parsing, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse HTML from [thisisnthappiness.com](http://thisisnthappiness.com/) site. For that I'm using Python's [HTMLParser](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html) library.

My goal is to get all data between tags that fit `div.post` (expressed as CSS selector).

This is my code so far:

```
import urllib2
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser


class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'div' and ('class', 'post') in attrs:
            print 'tag fits'


def main():
    parser = MyHTMLParser()
    resource = urllib2.urlopen('http://thisisnthappiness.com/')
    parser.feed(resource.read())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For now, it prints `tag fits` for several times. I'm on a half-way! :)

I'm stuck with getting data of tag that **fits** that CSS selector. In `handle_starttag()` I don't see any way to get data from that tag. Are there? I want to save data that's in the tag in list for further use.

Thanks in any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HTMLParser` is a very low level interface. You'll have to find the end tag and then deal with the html between the tags.

Here's what it looks like with [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html):

```
import lxml.html

def main():
    doc = lxml.html.parse("http://thisisnthappiness.com/").getroot()
    for e in doc.cssselect("div.post"):
       print e # this is an object representing the element

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This lets you use xpath, CSS selectors, the etree API or the DOM to query the data instead of reinventing the wheel.